# Looping through multiple arrays with np.where

Tags: python, loops, numpy

I have 2 lists distance_boundary and distance

```
distance_boundary = [100,200,300]
distance = [125,255,285,140,160,180]
```

Now I want to create a new variable **floor** and I want to assign the value for floor based on the distance value and it is defined by distance_boundary

For example ,

```
distance[0] is 125
```

since this is between distance_boundary[0] and distance_boundary[1]
so the corresponding value for floor should be 1

```
distance[1] is 255
```

since this is between distance_boundary[1] and distance_boundary[2]
so the corresponding value for floor should be 2

Looping through this should give me the final value of floor as

```
floor = [1,2,2,1,1,1]
```

I tried to loop through distance and used to np.where for assignment

```
floor = []

for j in range(0,len(distance)):

    floor = (np.where((distance[j]>distance_boundary[0]) & (distance[j]>distance_boundary[1]))
                      ,1,2)
    floor.append(floor)
```

This is not giving me desired result and moreover it is not looking scalable. 
Is there any other better solution

Comment: The condition in the np.where need to be modified to `np.where(distance[j]>distance_boundary[0] and distance[j]<distance_boundary[1], 1, 2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) seems to be what you are looking for:

```
np.searchsorted(distance_boundary, distance)
# array([1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, this is what I am looking for. One function solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas.cut`:

```
import pandas as pd

distance_boundary = [100,200,300]
distance = [125,255,285,140,160,180]

[distance_boundary.index(i.right) for i in pd.cut(distance, distance_boundary)]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```py
import numpy as np

distance_boundary = np.array([100,200,300])
distance = np.array([125,255,285,140,160,180])

floor = np.zeros_like(distance)
flag = (distance > 100) & (distance < 200)
floor[flag] = 1

flag = (distance > 200) & (distance < 300)
floor[flag] = 2

print(floor)
>>>[1 2 2 1 1 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an iterative approach. Sum the result of binary thresholds using each value in `distance_boundary` as the threshold:

```
import numpy as np

distance_boundary = np.array([100,200,300])
distance = np.array([125,255,285,140,160,180])

print(sum(np.where(distance > i, 1, 0) for i in distance_boundary))
```

This will print:

```
[1 2 2 1 1 1]
```

Comment: it infact works in the reverse manner sum(np.where(pressure < i, 1, 0) for i in floor_boundaries_inverse)

Answer (score 1):

O(N log N) solution:

```
    from bisect import bisect_left

    def binarySearch(num, arr):
        i = bisect_left(arr, num)
        if arr[i] == num:
            return i+1
        else:
            return i


    distance_boundary = [100,200,300]
    distance = [125,255,285,140,160,180]

    floor = list()
    for num in distance:
        floor.append(binarySearch(num, distance_boundary))

    print("floor =", floor)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your boundaries are always multiples of 100 this will work:

Code:

```
[int(str(q)[0:-2]) for q in distance]
```

Out:

```
[1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: I would upvote this for its being O(1), but  converting to string and back is just too wrong.

Comment: I agree, but it is fast. The "-2" could be converted to a variable if the boundaries are always "1 * 10^n", eliminating the boundary list. There's not necessarily a need to convert it back to an "int" type depending on the application.

Comment: Nowhere near as fast as `[q//100 for q in distance]` which also works for numbers that aren't powers of 10.